# main.js not found when loading angular2 app

Tags: angular

Angular2 application, when I am trying to load the app keeping the main.ts file within app folder it throws 404 NOT FOUND error for main.js file but when move main.ts file to the root folder it loads the app. Could anybody please explain this.
THANKS

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? and also ur index.html

Comment: How are you loading your js files? using script tags or systemjs (line in angular quickstart)?